# parse/ios device token registration failed (You have no registered installations of your app )

Tags: ios, parse-platform

i m trying to send push message to IOS device via parse . But seems to be device registration failed as "You have no registered installations of your app"  message appear in parse . used following code to register

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

No error occurs ,but registration filed.What could be the reason?????

Answer (score 0):

This seems like provisioning profile issue.

Ensure that you sync the profiles by going to `XCode > Preferences > Accounts > Your Account` and Select Application Id and press refresh button. Also, go to `Target > Build Settings > Code Signing` AND in `Project > Build Settings > Code Signing` and select correct provisioning profile and developer certificate.

Sometimes, deleting the old provisioning profile, downloading and installing the new profile followed by above mentioned steps also helps.